# How to loop a specific tone?

Tags: arduino-uno, speaker

I am building a security system, and found the following code

```
#define NOOT_B0  31
#define NOOT_C1  33
#define NOOT_D1  37
#define NOOT_E1  41
#define NOOT_F1  44
#define NOOT_G1  49
#define NOOT_A1  55
#define NOOT_B1  62
#define NOOT_C2  65
#define NOOT_D2  73
#define NOOT_E2  82
#define NOOT_F2  87
#define NOOT_G2  98
#define NOOT_A2  110
#define NOOT_B2  123
#define NOOT_C3  131
#define NOOT_D3  147
#define NOOT_E3  165
#define NOOT_F3  175
#define NOOT_G3  196
#define NOOT_A3  220
#define NOOT_B3  247
#define NOOT_C4  262
#define NOOT_D4  294
#define NOOT_E4  330
#define NOOT_F4  349
#define NOOT_G4  392
#define NOOT_A4  440
#define NOOT_B4  494
#define NOOT_C5  523
#define NOOT_D5  587
#define NOOT_E5  659
#define NOOT_F5  698
#define NOOT_G5  784
#define NOOT_A5  880
#define NOOT_B5  988
#define NOOT_C6  1047
#define NOOT_D6  1175
#define NOOT_E6  1319
#define NOOT_F6  1397
#define NOOT_G6  1568
#define NOOT_A6  1760
#define NOOT_B6  1976
#define NOOT_C7  2093
#define NOOT_D7  2349
#define NOOT_E7  2637
#define NOOT_F7  2794
#define NOOT_G7  3136
#define NOOT_A7  3520
#define NOOT_B7  3951
#define NOOT_C8  4186
#define NOOT_D8  4699


 int melody[] = {
// NOOT_C4, NOOT_G3, NOOT_G3, NOOT_A3, NOOT_G3, 0, NOOT_B3, NOOT_C4
NOOT_D8, NOOT_D8, NOOT_D8, NOOT_D8, NOOT_D8, NOOT_D8
};
int NOOTDurations[] = {
 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
 };
 void setup() {
    // iterate over the NOOTs of the melody:
  for (int thisNOOT = 0; thisNOOT < 8; thisNOOT++) {

// to calculate the NOOT duration, take one second divided by the NOOT type.
//e.g. quarter NOOT = 1000 / 4, eighth NOOT = 1000/8, etc.
int NOOTDuration = 1000 / NOOTDurations[thisNOOT];
tone(8, melody[thisNOOT], NOOTDuration);

// to distinguish the NOOTs, set a minimum time between them.
// the NOOT's duration + 30% seems to work well:
int pauseBetweenNOOTs = NOOTDuration * 1.50;
delay(pauseBetweenNOOTs);
// stop the tone playing:
noTone(8);
  }
 }

void loop() {
int melody[] = {
 // NOOT_C4, NOOT_G3, NOOT_G3, NOOT_A3, NOOT_G3, 0, NOOT_B3, NOOT_C4
 NOOT_D8, NOOT_D8, NOOT_D8, NOOT_D8, NOOT_D8, NOOT_D8
  };
 int NOOTDurations[] = {
  4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
  };

  }
```

How can i let the specific tone loop? Right now it's not within the loop and i am struggling to make it work in the loop. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So put the parts you think you need in the loop() and see what happens. If it doesn't work, post a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "Arduino.h"

const byte TONE_PIN = 4;
const int ALARM_BEEP_1 = 4186;
const int ALARM_BEEP_2 = 4699;

const int ALARM_TONE_LENGTH = 200;
const int ALARM_TONE_PAUSE = 800;
const int ALARM_TONE_REPEAT = 6;

boolean alarm = false;

void setup()
{
  alarm = true;
}

void loop()
{
  if (alarm) {
    alarmSound();
  }
}

void alarmSound() {
  static unsigned long next = millis();
  static byte count = 0;
  if (millis() > next) {
    next += ALARM_TONE_LENGTH;
    count++;
    if (count == ALARM_TONE_REPEAT) {
      next += ALARM_TONE_PAUSE;
      count = 0;
    }
    tone(TONE_PIN, (count % 2) ? ALARM_BEEP_1 : ALARM_BEEP_2, ALARM_TONE_LENGTH);
  }
}
```