# is there any archives of melody tones for buzzer used in arduino?

Tags: buzzer

I am using buzzer in my arduino and I read some articles about using array of tones(notes in music) with different frequencies to play play pleasant melodies.however, I do not find any site and archives for tones used in industrial, such as Start,Stop,warning,danger,next level,.... is there any site that collects these things and if not how can I create my own array of tones?

this is notes I have

```
#define NOTE_B0  31
#define NOTE_C1  33
#define NOTE_CS1 35
#define NOTE_D1  37
#define NOTE_DS1 39
#define NOTE_E1  41
#define NOTE_F1  44
#define NOTE_FS1 46
#define NOTE_G1  49
#define NOTE_GS1 52
#define NOTE_A1  55
#define NOTE_AS1 58
#define NOTE_B1  62
#define NOTE_C2  65
#define NOTE_CS2 69
#define NOTE_D2  73
#define NOTE_DS2 78
#define NOTE_E2  82
#define NOTE_F2  87
#define NOTE_FS2 93
#define NOTE_G2  98
#define NOTE_GS2 104
#define NOTE_A2  110
#define NOTE_AS2 117
#define NOTE_B2  123
#define NOTE_C3  131
#define NOTE_CS3 139
#define NOTE_D3  147
#define NOTE_DS3 156
#define NOTE_E3  165
#define NOTE_F3  175
#define NOTE_FS3 185
#define NOTE_G3  196
#define NOTE_GS3 208
#define NOTE_A3  220
#define NOTE_AS3 233
#define NOTE_B3  247
#define NOTE_C4  262
#define NOTE_CS4 277
#define NOTE_D4  294
#define NOTE_DS4 311
#define NOTE_E4  330
#define NOTE_F4  349
#define NOTE_FS4 370
#define NOTE_G4  392
#define NOTE_GS4 415
#define NOTE_A4  440
#define NOTE_AS4 466
#define NOTE_B4  494
#define NOTE_C5  523
#define NOTE_CS5 554
#define NOTE_D5  587
#define NOTE_DS5 622
#define NOTE_E5  659
#define NOTE_F5  698
#define NOTE_FS5 740
#define NOTE_G5  784
#define NOTE_GS5 831
#define NOTE_A5  880
#define NOTE_AS5 932
#define NOTE_B5  988
#define NOTE_C6  1047
#define NOTE_CS6 1109
#define NOTE_D6  1175
#define NOTE_DS6 1245
#define NOTE_E6  1319
#define NOTE_F6  1397
#define NOTE_FS6 1480
#define NOTE_G6  1568
#define NOTE_GS6 1661
#define NOTE_A6  1760
#define NOTE_AS6 1865
#define NOTE_B6  1976
#define NOTE_C7  2093
#define NOTE_CS7 2217
#define NOTE_D7  2349
#define NOTE_DS7 2489
#define NOTE_E7  2637
#define NOTE_F7  2794
#define NOTE_FS7 2960
#define NOTE_G7  3136
#define NOTE_GS7 3322
#define NOTE_A7  3520
#define NOTE_AS7 3729
#define NOTE_B7  3951
#define NOTE_C8  4186
#define NOTE_CS8 4435
#define NOTE_D8  4699
#define NOTE_DS8 4978
#define REST      0


// DURATION OF THE NOTES 
#define BPM 480      //you can change this value changing all the others
#define H 2*Q //half 2/4
#define Q 6000U/BPM //quarter 1/4 
#define E Q/2   //eighth 1/8
#define S Q/4 // sixteenth 1/16
#define W 4*Q // whole 4/4
```

Comment: There certainly wouldn't be a website that collects Arduino tone arrays. There may be examples around, but no one would collect the arrays together in one place - pretty pointless and obscure.  If you want to map the different musical notes to the actual frequencies then the examples in the IDE have "pitches.h" that contain macros that map the notes for you so you don't need to find out all the frequencies. Then it's just a matter of getting all the right notes in the right order with the right delays. How you implement that is up to you.

Comment: I already said that I need industrial notes. I have pitches.h and I need a site to that have a collection of melodies to choose. something to create different melodies for different situation.

Comment: There's plenty of places with sound samples of industrial situations - but you would have to transcribe those to individual notes for playing, which you'd need to do by hand.  Most "industrial" systems use sirens and klaxons with predefined tones built in.

Comment: not industrial by put the link here https://github.com/robsoncouto/arduino-songs and https://codebender.cc/sketch:238461#Songs%20on%20Piezo.ino

Comment: you don't really want to use pleasant melodies in an industrial setting

Comment: @jsotola,yeah I don't intend to put Super-mario melody . actually I need 2 or 3 Notes for a specific beep.

Comment: @david Could you further define what you mean by "industrial notes"? A "tone" and a "melody" are two different thinks, so I wonder whether you're looking for a song or a certain sound... btw, are you firm with how music "works"?

Comment: @SimSon I am not a musician everything I know are from articles I read and they may be incorrect but a "tone" is proportional to a frequency and declared by a Note. a melody is a train of tones. My definition of "Industrial Notes" is single or array of multiple tones that can be heard from an industrial device. for example warning signals is a repeatition of a single tone + no tone or if you might hear a beep in an elavator when it changes a level

Comment: Do you know `tone()`? (https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/). With this you can generate a tone, but composing a melody for start,stop,... is up to you.

Comment: maybe this may help you ... https://onlinesequencer.net/

Comment: try a sequence C5, E5, G5, C6

Comment: @jsotola thanks It was very Helpful,however I have to first set it to 8 bit square wave to get a real buzzer sound

Comment: see the toneMelody example in Arduino IDE. or try this sketch https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/48166/how-to-loop-a-specific-tone/48173#48173

Comment: or use this library https://github.com/evert-arias/EasyBuzzer

Comment: @Juraj, Thanks ,It was helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
#define NOTE_C4  262
#define NOTE_CS4 277
#define NOTE_D4  294
#define NOTE_DS4 311
#define NOTE_E4  330
#define NOTE_F4  349
#define NOTE_FS4 370
#define NOTE_G4  392
#define NOTE_GS4 415
#define NOTE_A4  440
#define NOTE_AS4 466
#define NOTE_B4  494
#define REST      0

int piezoPin = 13;
int numTones = 15;
int tempo = 2.5;

//Twinkle Twinkle Little Star:

int tones[] = {NOTE_C4, NOTE_C4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_F4, NOTE_F4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_D4, NOTE_D4, NOTE_C4, REST};

int duration[] = {500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 1000, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 1000, 4000};

void setup()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < numTones; i++)
  {
    tone(piezoPin, tones[i], duration[i] / tempo);
    delay(duration[i] / tempo);
  }
  noTone(piezoPin);
}

void loop()
{
} // Reset to play the song again
```

Comment: Twinkle twinkle.  Very industrial.